# practical disadvantages to using a computer as a wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, connection-sharing, internet-sharing

My wireless router is an ASUS RT-N66U.  It's having trouble achieving high speeds on my VPN.  I'm thinking of routing all VPN traffic through my Mac Mini's ethernet via a desktop client and sharing the internet connection via its wifi interface.  What practical disadvantages might I expect from such a course of action?  Please be specific.

Thank you

Comment: It is very unlikely the reason you are unable to achieve the speeds of your VPN is because of router, which means, connecting to your PC won't result in anything different.

Comment: First check if it's really the ASUS router that's the bottleneck (high CPU load), and not the fact that the VPN itself is congested, and doesn't allow more throughput.

Comment: my ASUS achieves quite high speeds without the VPN.  the tech support wants me to change a bunch of settings so it has an easier time decrypting traffic?  i'm pretty sure that's not the problem.  really just curious about using my computer as a router vs the asus hardware for multiple reasons.